# NSUserDefaults.removeObjectForKey not free memory?

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, nsuserdefaults

I use NSUserDefaults to share images between my custom keyboard and its container app.
Users can purchase many themes, that are downloaded only on-demand (using new iOS 9 feature "On demand resources").
Because of in-app purchases are available only in the container app, all the theme's images are downloaded and stored in the NSUserDefaults from the app, and then used by the keyboard.
I would to free memory occupied by the images stored in the NSUserDefaults (as NSData) if the user decide to change its theme.
I'm using the following code:

```
self.defaults.removeObjectForKey(IMAGE_KEY)
self.defaults.synchronize()
```

But if I then check the "Documents & Data" size of the app, no memory are released.
Any suggestion?

Comment: I don't think NSUserDefaults is supposed to be used to store large data objects like images...

Comment: Most definitely not. If you access _anything_ in NSUserDefaults, _everything_ must be read. If you change _anything_ _everything_ must be written. If you have hundred 10 MB images, that's one Gigabyte.

Comment: Yes, I know, but It's the only way to share data between an extension and its container app.